# Java method call issue, going back to main menu from a new .java class, possible array problem

Tags: java, class, methods, joptionpane

First I am sorry for all the questions but I am at a loss and have spent the last week working on this. I am new to the community so please work with me while I learn the format that I need to have in place.

Okay so I am working on my final project for a class and I have been given a help document and two .txt files. I have the .txt files on the right level where they can be called from any computer. I have also gotten my code to where it calls the right array to get a new submenu to come up after selection from the main menu. From there I am having problems calling a method (showdata) to have a JOptionPane pop up with an alert that must be displayed if there is a call for it from the .txt file namely it will have (*****) in front of it. I also have to add an option for the user to go back to the main menu instead of it just closing the program but I am unsure where I can put this option. I don't know if I should add it in the default loop or in my switch statement. Any help would be great. Thanks so much.

I have now included my .txt files below.

My main code is:
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Monitor {

    private static Scanner usrch = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnimalsHabitat methodCall = new AnimalsHabitat();

    try {

        int userChoice = mainMenu();

        switch(userChoice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please pick the animal you would like to monitor: ");
                System.out.println("");

                methodCall.askForWhichDetails("animals");

                System.out.println("Press 0 to go back.");

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Please pick the habitat you would like to monitor: ");
                System.out.println("");

                methodCall.askForWhichDetails("habitats");

                System.out.println("Press 0 to go back.");

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
                System.exit(0);

                break;

            default:
                int loopError = 0;

                while (loopError < 3) {
                    loopError++;

                    if (loopError == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Error in program loop, exiting program.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static int mainMenu() {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo Monitoring System!");
        System.out.println("Please select what you would like to monitor: ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1.) Animals");   
        System.out.println("2.) Habitats");   
        System.out.println("3.) Exit program");
        int userChoice = Integer.parseInt(usrch.nextLine());
        return userChoice;
    }
}
```

My help code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AnimalsHabitat {

    private String filePath;
    final private Scanner scnr;

    public AnimalsHabitat() {
        filePath = "";
        scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void askForWhichDetails(String fileName) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
        Scanner inFS = null;                   // Scanner object

        String textLine = null;
        ArrayList aList1 = new ArrayList();

        int i = 0;
        int option = 0;

        boolean bailOut = false;

        // Try to open file
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName + ".txt");
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        while (inFS.hasNextLine() && bailOut == false) {
            textLine = inFS.nextLine();

            if (textLine.contains("Details")) {
                i += 1;
                System.out.println(i + ". " + textLine);

                ArrayList aList2 = new ArrayList();

                for (String retval : textLine.split(" ")) {
                    aList2.add(retval);
                }

                String str = aList2.remove(2).toString();
                aList1.add(str);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Enter selection: ");
                option = scnr.nextInt();

                System.out.println("");

                if (option <= i) {
                    String detailOption = aList1.remove(option - 1).toString();
                    showData(fileName, detailOption);

                    bailOut = true;
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        // Done with file, so try to close it
        fileByteStream.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails  
    }

    public void showData(String fileName, String detailOption) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
        Scanner inFS = null;                   // Scanner object      

        String textLine = null;
        String lcTextLine = null;
        String alertMessage = "*****";

        int lcStr1Len = fileName.length();
        String lcStr1 = fileName.toLowerCase().substring(0, lcStr1Len - 1);

        int lcStr2Len = detailOption.length();
        String lcStr2 = detailOption.toLowerCase().substring(0, lcStr2Len - 1);

        boolean bailOut = false;

        // Try to open file
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName + ".txt");
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        while (inFS.hasNextLine() && bailOut == false) {
            textLine = inFS.nextLine();
            lcTextLine = textLine.toLowerCase();

            if (lcTextLine.contains(lcStr1) && lcTextLine.contains(lcStr2)) {
                do {
                    System.out.println(textLine);

                    textLine = inFS.nextLine();
                    if (textLine.isEmpty()) {
                        bailOut = true;
                    }

                    if (textLine.contains(alertMessage)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textLine.substring(5));
                    }

                } while (inFS.hasNextLine() && bailOut == false);
            }
        }

        // Done with file, so try to close it
        fileByteStream.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails      
    }

    void showData() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

This is my animals.txt

```
Details on lions
Details on tigers
Details on bears
Details on giraffes

Animal - Lion
Name: Leo
Age: 5
*****Health concerns: Cut on left front paw
Feeding schedule: Twice daily

Animal - Tiger
Name: Maj
Age: 15
Health concerns: None
Feeding schedule: 3x daily

Animal - Bear
Name: Baloo
Age: 1
Health concerns: None
*****Feeding schedule: None on record

Animal - Giraffe
Name: Spots
Age: 12
Health concerns: None
Feeding schedule: Grazing
```

This is my habitats.txt:

```
Details on penguin habitat
Details on bird house
Details on aquarium

Habitat - Penguin
Temperature: Freezing
*****Food source: Fish in water running low
Cleanliness: Passed

Habitat - Bird
Temperature: Moderate
Food source: Natural from environment
Cleanliness: Passed

Habitat - Aquarium
Temperature: Varies with output temperature
Food source: Added daily
*****Cleanliness: Needs cleaning from algae
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that I clicked on it by mistake.

Comment: No problem. My comments will self-destruct shortly.

Comment: It would be nice if you included your imports

Comment: I can include them if that would help.

Comment: Please include this information in your question. [edit] your question with the data.

Comment: I just included them above. Did I format them correctly for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

**Monitor.java**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Monitor
{

    private static Scanner usrch = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        AnimalsHabitat methodCall = new AnimalsHabitat();

        try
        {

            int userChoice = mainMenu();

            switch(userChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Please pick the animal you would like to monitor: ");
                System.out.println("");

                methodCall.askForWhichDetails("animals");
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Please pick the habitat you would like to monitor: ");
                System.out.println("");

                methodCall.askForWhichDetails("habitats");

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
                System.exit(0);

                break;

            default:
                int loopError = 0;

                while (loopError < 3)
                {
                    loopError++;

                    if (loopError == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error in program loop, exiting program.");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong input " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static int mainMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo Monitoring System!");
        System.out.println("Please select what you would like to monitor: ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("1.) Animals");
        System.out.println("2.) Habitats");
        System.out.println("3.) Exit program");
        int userChoice = Integer.parseInt(usrch.nextLine());
        return userChoice;
    }
}
```

**AnimalsHabitat.java**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AnimalsHabitat
{

    private String filePath;
    final private Scanner scnr;

    public AnimalsHabitat()
    {
        filePath = "";
        scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void askForWhichDetails(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
        Scanner inFS = null;                   // Scanner object

        String textLine = null;
        ArrayList aList1 = new ArrayList();

        int i = 0;
        int option = 0;

        boolean bailOut = false;

        // Try to open file
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName + ".txt");
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        while (inFS.hasNextLine() && bailOut == false)
        {
            textLine = inFS.nextLine();

            if (textLine.contains("Details"))
            {
                i += 1;
                System.out.println(i + ". " + textLine);

                ArrayList aList2 = new ArrayList();

                for (String retval : textLine.split(" "))
                {
                    aList2.add(retval);
                }

                String str = aList2.remove(2).toString();
                aList1.add(str);
            }
            else
            {
                while(option != (i + 1))
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter selection or enter " + (i + 1) + " to exit: ");
                    option = scnr.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("");

                    if (option <= i)
                    {
                        String detailOption = aList1.remove(option - 1).toString();
                        showData(fileName, detailOption);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        // Done with file, so try to close it
        fileByteStream.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails
    }

    public void showData(String fileName, String detailOption) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
        Scanner inFS = null;                   // Scanner object

        String textLine = null;
        String lcTextLine = null;
        String alertMessage = "*****";

        int lcStr1Len = fileName.length();
        String lcStr1 = fileName.toLowerCase().substring(0, lcStr1Len - 1);

        int lcStr2Len = detailOption.length();
        String lcStr2 = detailOption.toLowerCase().substring(0, lcStr2Len - 1);

        boolean bailOut = false;

        // Try to open file
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName + ".txt");
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        while (inFS.hasNextLine() && bailOut == false)
        {
            textLine = inFS.nextLine();
            lcTextLine = textLine.toLowerCase();

            if (lcTextLine.contains(lcStr1) && lcTextLine.contains(lcStr2))
            {
                do
                {
                    System.out.println(textLine);

                    textLine = inFS.nextLine();
                    if (textLine.isEmpty())
                    {
                        bailOut = true;
                    }

                    if (textLine.contains(alertMessage))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textLine.substring(5));
                    }

                }
                while (inFS.hasNextLine() && bailOut == false);
            }
        }

        // Done with file, so try to close it
        fileByteStream.close(); // close() may throw IOException if fails
    }

    void showData()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

**Run example**

```sh
javac AnimalsHabitat.java Monitor.java && java Monitor
```

Comment: In my opinion, it would be a lot better to be reading the files into an object or list of objects and then your display options logic, would not be tied to reading the file.

Comment: Hey, That did help to get the alert to come up but I am still having the issue on how to get it to give an option to go back to the main menu. Would that go into the default loop?

Comment: I showed something similar to what you are saying to my professor but he said it would be easier to just pull everything in from the help file and .txt documents. Is there a better way that you would suggest going about it so that I can achieve everything with a cleaner code? The way it is laid out now with the AnimalsHabitat.java is a little confusing to me still so I would like to make sure that while doing the work I understand everything that is going on too.

Comment: stay tuned, I'll throw an example together for you

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I just feel like this stuff was not covered very well in the class and I just want to make sure I learn it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of some menu and submenu selection

```java
package com.hnb;

public class Monitor {

    public Monitor(FileParser fileParser) {
        final Menu main = new Menu(fileParser.getOptions());
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo Monitoring System!");

        MenuSelection selection = null;
        Selection subselection = null;

        do {
            selection = main.displaySubMenu();
            if(selection.isValid()){
                do {
                    final Menu submenu = new Menu(selection.getSelection());
                    subselection = submenu.display();
                    if (subselection.isValid()) {
                        final Monitorable item = (Monitorable) subselection.getSelection();
                        System.out.println(item);
                        item.showAsterisk();
                    }
                } while (!subselection.isExit());
            }
        } while (!selection.isExit());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Monitor(new FileParser());
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the working example - https://github.com/spencerdcarlson/56826018